# I want to compare * as a literal by passin g it as command line argument

Tags: shell

I am exceuting a shell script from windows machine through plink.
I want to compare the "*" (passed as command line argument) to a literal in my script.
Can anyone suggest me the way to compare * as a literal?.
I have tried with all possible ways like including $1 in double quotes, single quotes, [].

Answer (score 4):

It's expanded by the shell so you have to pass it to the script either in quotes or escaped:

```
echo '*'
echo "*"
echo \*
```

Answer (score 2):

it should not be a problem, **the script:**

```
#! /bin/bash

if [[ "$1" == '*' ]]
then
  echo EQ
else
  echo NE
fi
```

**The execution:**

```
./aaa.bash '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that you need to quote the constant *, not the parameter that you are comparing it to.